# Datepicker is not working in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, datepicker, contact-form-7

I am working with Contact-form 7, the plugin Contact Form 7 – PayPal Add-on Version 1.3.4 was breaking the Datepicker functionality.

After Disabling this plugin made Datepicker Version 2.6.0 with Contact Form 7 version 4.7 work as expected on WordPress 4.5. 
Any solution ?? pls help me.
Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I sorted out my issue i used **https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-datepicker/** rather than Contact Form 7 - Datepicker plugin and it's working same as Contact Form 7 - Datepicker.
WP Datepicker is a great plugin to implement custom styled jQuery UI datepicker site-wide. You can set background images and manage CSS from your theme.